# ¿ Como mostrar primero algunas apps en un Intent implicito?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Estoy haciendo una app que envie mensajes, uno ingresa el texto por la app y al dar clic en Enviar la app lanza un selector de aplicaciones que pueden enviar el mensaje. El tema es que quiero que en el Selector de Aplicaciones (Intent implicito) salga primero: whatsapp, fb messenger, sms, etc.

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? He estado buscando en Internet pero no encuentro mucho contenido. Gracias

```
// Creo el Intent
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Mi texto a enviar");
intent.setType("text/plain");

// Comprueba que existan aplicaciones que puedan manejar el Intent
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean esIntentSeguro = activities.size() > 0;

// Si es seguro Enviar el Intent
if (esIntentSeguro) {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Elige por donde enviarás el mensaje ..."));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no se puede dar prioridad al listado de aplicaciones que aparecen en el dialog de compartir.
Una solución alternativa podría ser que generes tu propio dialog de compartir, con las opciones que tu desees. Una vez que el usuario seleccione una aplicación mandas ejecutar el `Intent.ACTION_SEND` directo a la app que el usuario halla seleccionado, aca un ejemplo:

```
miCustomDialog cd = new miCustomDialog(MainActivity.this);
//...... codigo de inicialicación de componentes del dialog personalizado que contiene las apps con las que deseas compartir
buttonWhats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         intent.setClassName("nombre del paquete de la app whatsapp"); //setClassName o setPackage cualquier opción que te funcione.
         intent.setPackage("nombre del paquete de la app whatsapp");
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Mi texto a enviar");
         intent.setType("text/plain");
         //...el resto de tu código
    }
});
cd.show();
```

Ojo que esto podría ser una mala practica debido que nada garantiza que el usuario tenga las apps instaladas en su dispositivo, además de que se debería desarrollar una buena función para determinar los nombres de los paquetes.